# PHP CAC Common Access Card Register and Login

Tags: php, ssl, pki, cac

I don't have a clue how to make my PHP website register and login with CAC Common Access Card. I developed for the past year a site and I can't sell it because off this. I have no clue. No HTTPS no SSL no PKI.

Comment: " no HTTPS no SSL no PKI. " what do you mean by this?

Comment: Closing as "unclear" or "too broad" - this question needs deleting.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set up server-side SSL.
2. Generate private CA for testing [if you don't have a CAC], issue an identity cert to self.
3. Install private CA as trusted root for client AuthN in application.
4. Require client-auth during SSL conversation; provide private CA and DoD Root CAs as trusted list of CAs.
5. Remove private CA from application trust after validation that it works.

Notes:

- You'll have to parse the user-supplied certs for your User ID.  This can come from the certificates signed by "DOD EMAIL CA-XX" [two digit number; presently up to 32] in the userPrincipalName field, or you can use the EDIPI which can be collected from either the DOD CA-XX certs or the DOD EMAIL CA-XX certs.  Done right, both of these IDs will be immutable over time and will reliably identify a user despite any name changes they may have.
- Any buyer worth their salt will demand that you're checking revocations via CRL or OCSP.  Be sure you configure this, probably caching the CRLs from each of the CAs on your local system for quick access and configurable refresh time.
- Assuming you're doing this in Apache, most of that work is documented in other threads here on SO and other sites.  Look around; you should find 90%+ of what you need.